# Mеню в Telebot в виде всплывающего окна

Tags: python, telebot, aiogram, меню

Хочу сделать меню команд для бота, в виде всплывающей менюшки.
В документации ничего не нашел (или плохо искал).
Отсюда вопрос: можно ли сделать что-то подобное на Telebot или только Aiogram так может?

Пример:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно:

1. Перейти в чат с BotFather
2. Написать команду `/mybots`
3. Выберите вашего бата и нажмите `Edit bot`
4. Далее переходите в `Edit Commands`

Вводите команды и их описание в таком формате по 1 команде за раз.

- команда1 - Описание
- комнада2 - Описание

Comment: Спасибо, все работает